# Hover on contact button and form field text colors

Tags: html, css

I want to change the hover on my contact button to border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)

I tried:

```
body.content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn, body.nested_content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;
}
```

But it doesn’t work.

I also want to change the pre-filled text color in the form fields to #000, but I don’t know how to.

Can someone please help?

I need to add !important to it because I am working with a existing CMS (like Wordpress) that has a stylesheet to it, but I can add adjustments to an custom stylesheet.

I am on my (new) iPad, which is my only device right now, and the inspect element apps are really letting me down :(

Thank you very much.

This the html code of the contact button:

```
<fieldset class="submit _4ORMAT_module_submit_left">
        <input class="btn primary _4ORMAT_module_contact_btn _4ORMAT_module_contact_input" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
        <div class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_label  " data-editable-type="label" id="label_4" style="display:none" data-force-html-mode="false" data-id="110586825" data-content-module-unique-id="">

   Send Message  
</div>
      </fieldset>
```

And this is the html code of the contact form

```css
body.content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn,
body.nested_content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;
}

/* Added after comment from @DafuQi */
input{
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form data-editable-type="contact-form" id="contact_form_1" class=" email_form" name="contact_form_1" action="/8939597/relay_email" method="POST" data-id="110586826" data-content-module-unique-id="">
  <div class="error_messages"></div>
  <div class="row naked">
    <div class="twelvecol last">
      <fieldset>
        <input class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_input" name="name" type="text" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
        <div class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_label  " data-editable-type="label" id="label_1" data-force-html-mode="false" data-id="110586822" data-content-module-unique-id="">

          Name
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row naked">
    <div class="twelvecol last">
      <fieldset class="_4ORMAT_module_input_active">
        <input class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_input" data-validate="email" name="from" type="email" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
        <div class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_label  " data-editable-type="label" id="label_2" data-force-html-mode="false" data-id="110586823" data-content-module-unique-id="">

          Email
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row naked last">
    <div class="twelvecol last">
      <fieldset>
        <textarea class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_input" data-validate="required" name="body" rows="8" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);"></textarea>
        <div class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_label  " data-editable-type="label" id="label_3" data-force-html-mode="false" data-id="110586824" data-content-module-unique-id="">

          Message
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="submit _4ORMAT_module_submit_left">
    <input class="btn primary _4ORMAT_module_contact_btn _4ORMAT_module_contact_input" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
    <div class="_4ORMAT_module_contact_label  " data-editable-type="label" id="label_4" style="display:none" data-force-html-mode="false" data-id="110586825" data-content-module-unique-id="">

      Send Message
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="GlEwaiZWvOfzyY+LGb4v9c7YEyQLVN5ta+4hHPhuM3cgUF9yIJjec90jNfF8/nBSLMFeLQ4umb0bvpbhCzE5nQ=="><input type="hidden" name="subject" value=""></form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please provide the code in the body of the question, instead of a link to the code.  The reason is that once you fix this problem, the post loses all value moving forwards because the conditions that caused the issue are lost to time.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to figure out how to edit my original question and add the code to it.

Comment: I just added the html code to my question, I hope my question can be better answered now.

Comment: I put an eye on the first thing, border color of hover the send message button, i copy the code they used to select it, and put it with !important (as you did) but i guess you are trying to put border black on focus, when its already border black, am i wrong? (i tried changing color to red for exemple it worked

Comment: body.content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn:hover, body.nested_content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn:hover {
    border-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, 1) !important;
}

Comment: @DafuQi No, I tried this and it doesn’t work.

Comment: @SilvanSoeters the css is loaded before or after the one of the cms...?

Comment: @DafuQi After :)

Comment: @SilvanSoeters well if the code i gave (if you want to copy easier i edit my post under) dont work... i wish you a good day and good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the hover button issue: `input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn:hover { background-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, 1) !important; }`

See comment by @DafuQi for solution for changing the input text color of a form field.

Answer (score 0):

button:hover{ border: 2px solid red;  }

Answer (score -1):

So change the color of a button on hover?

```
#button:hover{
    background-color: X;
}
```

and to change the color of an input text

```
input{
    color: X;
}
```

was that what you needed?

AND PLEASE: never use !important in css thats hell...

in css the selector is working like this:

1. the most precise win (imagine : body div .X #Y is over than div .X #Y).

2. if the precision are equal, the last instruction win.

EDIT: ok so for prepare code, may you try:

```
body.content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row ._4ORMAT_module_contact_label, body.content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row textarea._4ORMAT_module_contact_input, body.content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input:not(.btn), body.nested_content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row ._4ORMAT_module_contact_label, body.nested_content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row textarea._4ORMAT_module_contact_input, body.nested_content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input:not(.btn) {
    color: red !important;
}


body.content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn:hover, body.nested_content:not(.client):not(.store):not(.product):not(.blog) :not(._4ORMAT_content_page_TITLE) ._4ORMAT_content_page_row input._4ORMAT_module_contact_input.btn:hover { 
    border-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, 1) !important; 
}
```

Comment: This is not even close to what OP asked

Comment: Sorry, no, please see the actual website (case)

Comment: @mplungjan well sorry i hear: I want to change the hover on my contact button to border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) and I also want to change the pre-filled text color in the form fields to #000, but I don’t know how to.

at least i tried...

Comment: @SilvanSoeters Well sorry, even after i read your message again i don't understand what you are waiting for, hope people may help you

Comment: @DafuQi I am hoping for a solution to the exact case I am referring to, I just added the html code what it is about! I just read only a link to the page is a no go because of changes that can be made later on and therefore my question loses its value to reader in the future.

Comment: @SilvanSoeters so my answer was good but you need a ready to use code?

Comment: @DafuQi Yes. I know how to add a hover but and change input text colors normally but the code from my CMS which I’m using is giving me a hard time because I can’t inspect elements properly on my iPad.

Comment: @DafuQi please take a look at the code I added if you will

Comment: @SilvanSoeters answered under main post, may you tell me if it work? if it don't i'll leave my place

Comment: I used your code “ input{color: X;}” and it worked. Thanks! I solved the button hover myself.